# How can I open a NSOpenPanel not modally (since I'm opening to an existing sheet)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a NSPanel and I need to load a file path into one of its fields.

I'm currently using:

```
NSOpenPanel *browsePanel = [[NSOpenPanel alloc] init];
[browsePanel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[browsePanel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[browsePanel setCanCreateDirectories:NO];
[browsePanel beginSheetForDirectory:nil
                               file:nil
                              types:nil
                     modalForWindow:[self window]
                      modalDelegate:self
                     didEndSelector:@selector(browsePanelPanelDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                        contextInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[sender tag]]
 ];
```

But the NSOpenPanel sheet doesn't show up, and I don't get any error message in the console.
I guess it is because I'm opening it from an existing sheet and I can't load more than 1 sheet per time.

So I'm now using [browsePanel makeKeyAndOrderFront:[self window]]; but I get 2 problems:

1. the panel is always on the back of my modal sheet, I can't display it on top. Also, I can't move the focus which remains on the original sheet.
2. How do I assign the end selector, to process the data, if I don't load it modally ?

Thanks

Comment: You already answered yourself. One sheet per window. You could be retarded and open a new window to run a new sheet. Bad design though in most cases.

Comment: you do sometimes see one sheet replacing another sheet on the same window, but yes, maybe that's inadvisable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Presenting a Series of Sheets](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingCascadingSheets.html):

> Cocoa does not support the notion of cascading, or nested sheets. Per *Apple Human Interface Guidelines*, “when the user responds to a sheet, and another sheet for that document opens, the first sheet must close before the second one opens.”

The doc goes on to tell you how to present a *series* of sheets, as the second opens it closes the first, etc.

You either need to adopt such a series or change your design so your first sheet, the one calling NSOpenPanel, is not a sheet at all.

**FYI:** In the sandboxed world `NSOpenPanel` is a very different beast while maintaining essentially the same UI. Among the changes are that `NSOpenPanel` is no longer a subclass of `NSWindow`... Tricks you might play now with `NSOpenPanel` may crash and burn under sandboxing, tread lightly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using :

```
- (void)beginSheetForDirectory:(NSString *)path file:(NSString *)name types:(NSArray *)fileTypes modalForWindow:(NSWindow *)docWindow modalDelegate:(id)delegate didEndSelector:(SEL)didEndSelector contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo NS_DEPRECATED_MAC(10_0, 10_6);
```

Which is deprecated. You should use

```
[browsePanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:nil];
```

EDIT:

[Check this running project](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5873936/browsermodalnsopenpanel-34k?da=y).

Comment: beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler: is not supported by Leopard and my app is still supporting it. I tried the other method, but it doesn't solve the issue, still no sheet.

Comment: Check my edit with link to running project if it can help you.

Comment: But in your code you are not loading the NSOpenPanel from a NSPanel as I specified in the question. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: So you have another controller class for NSPanel window? As i have same controler for both and the openPanel is opening on panel window.

Comment: I meant that you are using NSWindow classes and not NSPanel and NSOpenPanel

Answer (score 0):

One sheet per *window*. More sheets means more windows and weird UI.